# Write DWORD Value with Python's _winreg?

Tags: python, windows, registry, winreg

I'm working on a project that requires me to write a DWORD value to the registry. I know how to write other values, but I'm not sure how to write this value.

I need it to be set to 1. How is this done using _winreg with Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SetValueEx() to set the value and the type, types are listed here: http://docs.python.org/library/_winreg.html#value-types
You probably want _winreg.REG_DWORD